# RSS feed not detected when rendered with PHP but detected rendered as static XML file

Tags: php, xml, rss

I generated an RSS feed using some data from arrays, it validates and conforms to the spec but when I render it out in PHP from a url like http://example.com/feed and try to open it in a news reader, the reader tells me no feed is present. If I serve is as a static file however http://example.com/feed.xml, it loads. What am I missing here?

Sample Feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Exampel feed</title>
        <description>Example RSS Feed</description>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <subtitle>Test feed</subtitle>
        <item>
            <title>Equations</title>
            <link>http://example.com</link>
            <pubDate>Wed, 12 Oct 2015 08:00:00 EST</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I also changed the mime type, `header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: I'm trying this in feedreader.com btw.

Comment: You should verify that it's indeed the same output by manually visiting `/feed`, and comparing it to what happens when you visit `/feed.xml`. If you don't have URL rewriting set up, `/feed.php` is not the same as `/feed`.